# ¿Como seleccionar por defecto un elemento de un jcombobox que se carga desde una clase?

Tags: java

Tengo un jcombobox que carga las regiones de Chile, utilizo una clase llamada Regiones para así guardar tambien el ID.
Necesito que al consultar los datos de una persona se cargue el jcombobox (lo cual lo hace sin problemas), pero tambien necesito que se seleccione la region de la persona.
No puedo usar simplemente un .setSelectedItem("Nombre-de-la-region") porque el combobox solo recive objetos de la clase Regiones.

El código de la clase es este:

```
public class Regiones {

    public int id;
    public String nombre, num_r;

    Connection connect;


    public Regiones(int id, String nombre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Regiones() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNum_r() {
        return num_r;
    }

    public void setNum_r(Integer id) {
        this.num_r = num_r;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public void cargarR(JComboBox<Regiones> cbx_region){
        connect = Conexion.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM region WHERE ACTIVO_REGION = 'SI';";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
                if (i == 0){
                    int a = 0; String b ="", c ="Seleccionar Región";
                    cbx_region.addItem(
                        new Regiones(
                            a,
                            c
                        )
                    );
                }
                else{
                while(rs.next()){
                    cbx_region.addItem(
                            new Regiones(
                                rs.getInt("ID_REGION"),
                                rs.getString("NUM_REGION")+" - "+ rs.getString("NOMBRE_REG")
                            )
                    );
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Regiones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}


@Override
public String toString(){

    return nombre;
}
```

}

Y para cargar el combobox, el código es este:

```
Regiones rg = new Regiones();
rg.cargarR(cbx_region);
```

Pero no se como seleccionar una región por defecto.

Comment: Hola buenas, mira mi respuesta. Y mientras: Tienes una clase `Persona` y un metodo `getRegion()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar un elemento del combobox se usa:

- [setSelectedIndex()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex(int))  para pasar el indice que ocupa el elemento que quieres marcar
- [setSelectedItem()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)) para seleccionar un item por valor

En tu caso dices que el segundo no te vale, asi que puedes usar el primero.

Ej:

```
JComboBox test = new JComboBox();
test.addItem(new ComboItem(0, "Pan"));
test.addItem(new ComboItem(1, "leche"));
test.addItem(new ComboItem(2, "huevos"));
test.addItem(new ComboItem(3, "manzanas"));

//para seleccionar el de ID = 2, huevos
test.setSelectedIndex(2);

//para seleccionar el de valor "manzanas
test.setSelectedItem("manzanas");
```

<sub>Nota: si alguna instrucción no correspondiera (ej: `test.setSelectedIndex(5); // no hay index 5 en test` ) no fallaría el programa y quedaría seleccionado el que ya lo estuviera y se continuaría con la ejecución del programa.</sub>

Comment: Puede usar el segundo caso, pero no con `String` sino con una instancia de `Región`: `setSelectedItem(persona.getRegion());` asumiendo que el objeto persona tiene un método como `getRegion()` que devuelva la región. Si editas tu respuesta con esto estaría perfecta.

Comment: Gracias @Awes0meM4n. Parece que el nombre si hace la cosa xD Pero de donde sale `persona`?

Comment: He asumido que algo parecido debe tener el OP porque dice _necesito que se seleccione la region de la persona_ pero que no puede buscarlo por el nombre. Puede que lo que devuelva sea el `String` del nombre de la región, en cuyo caso lo mejor sería implementar un `get` de región para esto.

Comment: Si, @Awes0meM4n seria lo asumible pero a saber xD mejor que nos explique si tiene metodos que saquen esa informacion

Comment: Por supuesto, pero creo que le será más fácil acceder a la región así que obtener el índice para cada región según se cargó el combo .Si te fijas como lo carga no tiene ningún control sobre los índices simplemente agrega elementos desde el `ResultSet` (yo lo haría así también pero con un `try-with-resources` que me lo cerraría todo, aunque eso es otro tema).

Comment: Ya, @Awes0meM4n. pense en poner un `order by Id_region` . Aunque teniendo `WHERE ACTIVO_REGION = 'SI'` hace que los Id no estén seguidos xD